# Change post value in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How change existing value to new and keep data ?

I changed the name in acf and now my new data is not updated

```
$post_desc = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_desc', true);
$post_id = get_the_ID();

$value = get_post_custom_values(get_the_ID(), $post_desc);
    foreach ($value as $values)
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_desc', $post_desc );
```

post_desc - is new name on acf

Comment: [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/#getting-started) is not exactly the same as a [Custom Field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). Are you sure you're making the change in the right place?

Comment: but i want change acf value, i renamed old acf name to new, but content is not updating

Comment: In that case, you should be using [update_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) instead.

Comment: This way is not correct change values in all posts